# What's wrong with my shiny app code? Everytime I run it, it shuts down

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote this code for my R assignment, and every time I run it, it crashes. I am guessing there is an error that's making it terminate.

Anyone can tell me what it is?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes) library(tidyverse) library(DT)
load("~/Desktop/Yasmine Nahdi - Fifa Analysis - FINAL/fifa.RData")


main_page <- tabPanel(   title = "Player Analysis",   titlePanel("Player Analysis"),   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      sliderInput("year", h4("Year"), sep = "", 
                  min = 2017, max = 2021,
                  value = c(2018, 2020), step = 1),
      numericInput("max_country", h4("Nationality/Country"), 
                   min = 2, max = 12, step = 1, value = 6),
      selectInput("short_name", h4("Player"),
                  choices = c("All players", as.character(unique(fifa$short_name))),
                  selected = c("All players"), multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput("team_position", h4("Player positions"),
                  choices = c("All positions", as.character(unique(fifa$team_position)) ),
                  selected = c("All positions"), multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plots",
          fluidRow(column(6, plotOutput("playerage")), 
                   column(6, plotOutput("weightvsmovement"))),
          fluidRow(column(6, plotOutput("playerBMI")),
                   column(6, plotOutput("movementvsBMI"))),
          fluidRow(column(6, plotOutput("nationalitybyposition")), 
                   column(6, plotOutput("valuebyposition"))))
        )
      )
    )   )

about_page <- tabPanel(   title = "About" )

ui <- navbarPage(   theme = shinytheme('united'),   title = "Fifa Career Mode Analysis",    main_page,    about_page )



server <- function(input, output){   data <- reactive({ 
    if(input$short_name == "All players"){
      fifa %>%          
        filter(year >= input$year[1], 
               year <= input$year[2]) 
    } else {
      fifa %>%                 
        filter(year >= input$year[1], 
               year <= input$year[2],
               Player %in% input$short_name) 
    }   })
  
     # (1) General Analysis : Player-focused  
     #distribution of players ages    output$playerage <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = age)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(age)), linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
      theme_minimal() +
      ggtitle("Distribution of Players' age")   })
     #player weight vs movement   output$weightvsmovement <- renderPlot({
    data() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x= weight_kg, y=Movement, color=overall)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle("Players' movement in relation to their weight(kg)")   })
     #distribution of player BMI   output$playerBMI <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      mutate(BMI = weight_kg / (height_cm**2) *10000) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = BMI)) + 
      geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + 
      geom_density(color = "red") +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(BMI)), linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
      theme_minimal() +
      ggtitle("Distribution of Players' BMI") +
      labs(y= "Density", x = "BMI")   })
     #movement by BMI   output$movementvsBMI <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      mutate(BMI = weight_kg / (height_cm**2) *10000) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = BMI, y= Movement)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth( se =F) + 
      ggtitle("Players' movement in relation to their BMI")   })
     #players preferred foot   output$preferredfoot <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = preferred_foot)) + 
      geom_bar() + 
      theme_minimal() + 
      ggtitle("Player's preferred foot count") + 
      labs(x= "Preferred foot", y="Number of players")   })
  

  # Correlation between player position, age, and performance
     attackers <- c("ST","CF","RW","LW","LF","RF", "LS")   midfielders <- c("CM","CAM","CDM","LM","RM","LAM","RAM","LCM","RCM","RDM","LDM")   defenders <- c("CB","LB","RB","RWB","LWB","RCB","LCB")   other <- c("SUB", "RES")
     filter_position <- reactive({
    if(input$team_position == "All positions"){
      fifa %>%
        filter(year >= input$year[1], 
               year <= input$year[2])
    } else {
      fifa %>%
        filter(year >= input$year[1], 
               year <= input$year[2],
               team_position %in% input$team_position)
    }   })
     output$positionageperf <- renderPlot({
    fifa <- fifa %>% 
      mutate(Position = case_when(
        team_position %in% attackers ~ "Attacker",
        team_position %in% midfielders ~ "Midfielder",
        team_position %in% defenders ~ "Defender",
        team_position %in% other ~ "Other"))
    data() %>%
      filter (Position %in% c("Attacker", "Midfielder", "Defender")) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = age, y = overall, colour = Position )) + geom_point()  + 
      theme_minimal() + geom_smooth( se = F) + ggtitle("Analysis of player's performance with age") + xlab("Player age") + ylab("Player overall performance")   })
     #Player analysis by position   #Most common player nationalities based on position   output$nationalitybyposition <- renderPlot({
    filter_position() %>% 
      group_by(nationality) %>%
      mutate(nat_number = n()) %>%
      filter(nat_number > 10) %>%
      ggplot(aes(y= reorder(nationality, nat_number))) + geom_bar() + theme_minimal() + ggtitle("Most common nationality of selected player position (by year/period))") + xlab("Number of players") + ylab("Country")   })
     #highest valued player by position   output$valuebyposition <- renderPlot({
    filter_position() %>%
      arrange(desc(value_eur)) %>%
      filter (value_eur > 34500000) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = short_name, y=value_eur)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle("Highest valued player by position") + 
      xlab("Player name") + 
      ylab("Value (euros)")    })
     #(2) League analysis
     premierLeague <- c("Arsenal", "Aston Villa", "Brighton & Hove Albion", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Fulham", "Leeds United", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Manchester City", "Manchester United", "Newcastle United", "Sheffield United", "Southampton", "Tottenham Hotspur", "West Bromwich Albion", "West Ham United", "Wolverhampton Wanderers")    bundesliga <- c("1. FC Köln", "1. FSV Mainz 05", "DSC Arminia Bielefeld", "Borussia Dortmund", "FC Augsburg", "FC Bayern München", "FC Schalke 04", "Eintracht Frankfurt", "Hertha BSC", "Bayer 04 Leverkusen", "Borussia Mönchengladbach", "RB Leipzig", "SC Freiburg", "TSG 1899 Hoffenheim", "1. FC Union Berlin", "VfB Stuttgart", "VfL Wolfsburg", "SV Werder Bremen")   laliga <- c("Athletic Club de Bilbao", "Atlético Madrid", "CA Osasuna", "Cádiz CF", "Deportivo Alavés", "Elche CF", "FC Barcelona", "Getafe CF", "Granada CF", "Levante UD", "Real Valladolid CF", "RC Celta", "Real Betis", "Real Madrid", "Real Sociedad", "SD Eibar", "SD Huesca", "Sevilla FC", "Valencia CF", "Villarreal CF")   seriea <- c("Atalanta", "Benevento", "Bologna", "Cagliari", "Crotone", "Fiorentina", "Genoa","Hellas Verona","Inter", "Spezia", "Lazio", "Milan", "Napoli", "Parma", "Juventus", "Roma","Sampdoria","Sassuolo","Torino", "Udinese")   ligue1 <- c("Angers SCO", "AS Monaco", "AS Saint-Étienne", "FC Girondins de Bordeaux", "Dijon FCO", "FC Lorient", "FC Metz", "FC Nantes", "LOSC Lille", "Montpellier HSC", "Nîmes Olympique", "OGC Nice", "Olympique Lyonnais", "Olympique de Marseille", "Paris Saint-Germain", "Racing Club de Lens", "Stade Rennais FC", "Stade Brestois 29", "Stade de Reims", "RC Strasbourg Alsace")
     FifaLeague <- fifa %>% mutate(League = case_when(
    club_name %in% bundesliga ~ "Bundesliga",
    club_name %in% premierLeague ~ "Premier League",
    club_name %in% laliga ~ "La Liga",
    club_name %in% seriea ~ "Serie A",
    club_name %in% ligue1 ~ "Ligue 1"   ))
     FifaLeague <- na.omit(FifaLeague)
     filter_league <- reactive({
    FifaLeague %>% 
      filter(year >= input$year[1],
             year <= input$year[2])   }) }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code is for an assignment I am doing to analyze the FIFA 2017 to 2021 players. the idea is to create a shiny app where the user can select inputs and the plots get updated.

Let me know if there is anything else I can do to explain further.
Thank you!

Comment: Look at this line, for example: `#Player analysis by position   #Most common player nationalities based on position   output$nationalitybyposition <- renderPlot({`.  You've commented out the start of a call to `renderPlot`.  Hence disaster.  Check your code carefully.  Syntax highlighting in RStudio is a wonderful thing!  There may be other similar examples.  Your code is not reproducible as we don't have access to your desktop so can't load your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will recheck it carefully!